# Setting numerator terms to zero only

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I have many expressions of the form $c_1/\epsilon, c_2/\epsilon \dots ,c_n/\epsilon$ where $n$ is a large number and I also have expressions of the form $b_1\epsilon, b_2\epsilon, \dots ,b_m \epsilon$ where $m$ is also very large. $c_i$ and $b_i$ are just $\epsilon$-independent variables or numbers.

I would like to put the terms in which $\epsilon$ appears in the numerator to zero without affecting the terms in which $\epsilon$ appears in the denominator. Is there a way to automate this in Mathematica? Probably the answer is yes and the solution is very simple but I have not found the correct syntax yet.

```
   expr/.eps->0
```

gives rise to errors because of producing indeterminate forms, as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: Would something like `(Numerator[expr] /. eps -> 0)/Denominator[expr]` work?

Comment: `(b1 \[Epsilon])/n1 + k1/\[Epsilon] + (b2 \[Epsilon])/n2  + 
  k2/\[Epsilon] /. Power[\[Epsilon], -1] :> 0` ??

Comment: @J.M That gave me a 1/0 error again :/

Comment: @AliHashmi This works except it gets rid of the denominator terms instead. If I replace -1 with +1 it gives me an error.

Comment: Could you post an example expression, then? It's hard to give a useful suggestion if other people can only guess at what your expressions look like.

Comment: Sure, here is one such term of each kind, but as I wrote in the question, the $c_i$ are $b_i$ are epsilon independent. $$\frac{(256 \epsilon m_1)}{(\text{M}^3 (-1 + xb) (1 + xb))}$$ and $$\frac{(256 m2)}{(\epsilon \text{M} (-1 + xb) (1 + xb))}$$

Comment: You should edit your question to include your examples (in code blocks) rather than put them in comments. For the examples that you provide, @J.M. comment works. Either, `(Numerator[list] /. eps -> 0)/Denominator[list]` or `(Numerator[#] /. eps -> 0)/Denominator[#] & /@ list`.

Comment: (Currently broken in `Series` but fixed in development).  `ll = {a/eps, b*eps/c, d/e}; InputForm[Normal[Series[ll, {eps, 0, 0}]]]                              

Out[4]//InputForm= {a/eps, 0, d/e}`

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = 
  {(256 m2)/(ϵ M (-1 + b x) (1 + b x)), (256 ϵ m1)/(M^3 (-1 + b x) (1 + b x))};

Replace[#,Times[PatternSequence[___, Verbatim[ϵ]]] -> 0, {1}] & /@ expr
(* {(256 m2)/(M (-1 + b x) (1 + b x) ϵ), 0} *)
```

Comment: I made an edit. since the attribute of `Times` is `Orderless` we do not need `OrderlessPatternSequence` and therefore `PatternSequence` will suffice

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to obtain a more direct route but the following simple trick gets the job done:

```
   expr/.{1/eps->x};
   %/.{eps->0}
   %/.{x->1/eps}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use @DanielLichtblau's solution from the comments:

```
Normal @ Series[{b1 ϵ, b2 ϵ, c1/ϵ, b3 ϵ, c2/ϵ, c3/ϵ}, {ϵ, 0, 0}]
```

> {0, 0, c1/ϵ, 0, c2/ϵ, c3/ϵ}

Answer (score 0):

If the input expression `expr` *only* contains terms of the form `1/eps` and `eps`, then you can use `Coefficient`:

```
Dot[Coefficient[expr, eps, {-1, 0}], {1/eps, 1}]
```